# How to find $4$-tuple parametric representation of Möbius strip?

Tags: general-topology, parametric, geometric-topology

We know that a Möbius strip can be constructed as follow:
$$M\cong \frac{\Bbb S^1\times \Bbb S^1}{\Bbb Z_2},$$
where $\Bbb Z_2$ act by permutation. So I think that it is possible  represent each point of $M$ by $4$-tuple $(x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2)$ (see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1396314/272127) for $3$-tuple case).

> How to find this parametric representation of Möbius strip?

Comment: If you have a $3$-tuple parametrization then you always have $X$-tuple parametrization for $X>3$ simply by taking constant coordinates after the third one. Or what exactly you are looking for?

Comment: I want this parametric equation using the above construction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have two kinds of Möbius strips.

1. Let $[0,1]\times[0,1]=\{(s,t)\mid 0\leq s,t\leq 1\}$. Then the quotient space $([0,1]\times[0,1])/\sim$ is a Möbius strip, where $(s,0)\sim(1-s,1)$.
2. Let $S^1\times S^1=\{(e^{2\pi is},e^{2\pi it}) \mid 0\leq s,t\leq 1\}$ be a torus. Then the quotient space $(S^1\times S^1)/\sim$ is a Möbius strip, where $(e^{2\pi is},e^{2\pi it})\sim(e^{2\pi it},e^{2\pi is})$.

**[Reference]** The accepted answer of "[Orbit space of torus homeomorphic to mobius strip](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1880686/orbit-space-of-torus-homeomorphic-to-mobius-strip)"

We want to find a **parametrization** $f\colon [0,1]\times[0,1]\to(S^1\times S^1)/\sim$ with two variables $(s,t)\in[0,1]\times[0,1]$.

[image]

> At first define $f_1\colon [0,1-t]\times[0,1]\to S^1\times S^1$ and $f_2\colon [1-t,1]\times[0,1]\to S^1\times S^1$ by
>   $$
> \begin{cases}
> f_1(s,t)=\left( e^{\pi i(1-t+s)}, e^{\pi i(1-t-s)} \right), & \text{$0\leq s\leq 1-t$} \\
> f_2(s,t)=\left( e^{\pi i(3-t-s)}, e^{\pi i(1-t+s)} \right), & \text{$1-t\leq s\leq1$}
> \end{cases} \tag{*}
> $$

Then $f_1(1-t,t)=(e^{2\pi i(1-t)},1)\sim(1,e^{2\pi i(1-t)})=f_2(1-t,t)$. Attaching $f_1$ and $f_2$ along the line $s=1-t$ we have a continuous surjection
$$
f\colon [0,1]\times[0,1] \to (S^1\times S^1)/\sim
$$

Moreover, $f$ induces a homeomorphism between the two Möbius strips 
$$
\tilde f\colon ([0,1]\times[0,1])/\sim \, \to (S^1\times S^1)/\sim
$$
since for all $0\leq s\leq1$,
$$
f(s,0) = f_1(s,0) = (e^{\pi i(1+s)},e^{\pi i(1-s)}) = f_2(1-s,1) = f(1-s,1)
$$

> We can rewrite the parametrization (*) with 4-tuples as follows:
>   $$
> \begin{align*}
> f(s,t)=f_1(s,t) = \bigl( &\cos\bigl[\pi(1-t+s)\bigr], \sin\bigl[\pi(1-t+s)\bigr], \\
> &\cos\bigl[\pi(1-t-s)\bigr], \sin\bigl[\pi(1-t-s)\bigr] \bigr)
> \end{align*}
> $$
>   for $0\leq s\leq 1-t$, and
>   $$
> \begin{align*}
> f(s,t)=f_2(s,t) = \bigl( &\cos\bigl[\pi(1-t-s)\bigr], \sin\bigl[\pi(1-t-s)\bigr], \\
>  &\cos\bigl[\pi(1-t+s)\bigr], \sin\bigl[\pi(1-t+s)\bigr] \bigr)
> \end{align*}
> $$
>   for $1-t\leq s\leq 1$.

Note that $f_1(s,t)$ is the same as $f_2(s,t)$ in the quotient space $(S^1\times S^1)/\sim$.