# Find the equation of surface in parametric form

Tags: geometry, 3d, geometric-topology

A line segment AB joining the points $A(10,0,0)$ & $B(20,0,0)$ is rotated about the y-axis through an angle of $2\pi$ & simultaneously it rotated through an angle of $\pi$ about its mid point in the plane containing it & the axis of rotation (i.e. y-axis). Find the parametric equation of surface generated if forms of coordinates
 $$ X,Y, Z $$
My Try:
for complete rotation about y-axis in X-Z plane & half rotation , I have $$X=r\cos \theta, Z=r\sin\theta $$
where, $10\leq r\leq 20 $,  $0\leq \theta\leq 2\pi $

for secondary rotation I get y-coordinate 
$$Y=\frac{(20-10)}{2}\sin\frac{\theta}{2}=5\sin\frac{\theta}{2}$$
I don't know if I am correct. Please help me solve this problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result is a ["Möbius strip"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/638225) as shown here :

[image]

You have more or less found the different elements for a natural parametrization.

The final step is made clear if one adopts this matrix-vector formulation :

$$\begin{pmatrix}X\\Y\\Z\end{pmatrix}=\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta&0&-\sin\theta\\
    0&1&0\\
    \sin\theta&0& \ \ \cos\theta\end{pmatrix}}_{R_{\theta}}
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}15+u\cos(\theta/2)\\
      u\sin(\theta/2)\\0\end{pmatrix}}_V \ \ \text{for} \ \ \begin{cases} \ \ \ 0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi\\-5\leq u \leq 5\end{cases}$$

otherwise said :

$$\begin{pmatrix}X\\Y\\Z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}(\cos\theta)(15+u\cos(\theta/2))\\
    u\sin(\theta/2)\\
    (\sin\theta)(15+u\cos(\theta/2))\end{pmatrix} \ \ \text{for} \ \ \begin{cases} \ \ \ 0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi\\-5\leq u \leq 5\end{cases}$$ 
where

- $R_{\theta}$ is the rotation matrix of angle $\theta$ around $y$ axis,
- $V$ accounts for the line segment of length $10$ turning "at half-speed" around its midpoint $(15,0,0)$ **in the $x0y$ plane** (this is maybe the most notable thing to understand), where $u$ allows to sweep each segment for a fixed $\theta$.

The Matlab program for the figure:

> ```
>    view([20,18]);
>    ub=-5;ue=5;
>    for t=0:pi/30:2*pi
>        Ry=[cos(t),0,-sin(t);
>        0,1,0;
>        sin(t),0,cos(t)];
>        V=[15+ub*cos(t/2),15+ue*cos(t/2);
>           ub*sin(t/2),ue*sin(t/2);
>           0,0];
>        W=R*V;
>        plot3(W(1,:),W(2,:),W(3,:));
>    end;
> ```

Comment: The reference I just added contains a derivation very close to the one I have given.

Comment: thank you very much. it really helped me